# Replacing , with . for each cell in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to change the comma `,` to `.` if a cell contains a comma `,`.

I was able to do it for a dash `-` to a `NullString`, but some of the cell values contain a `-` as well as a `,`, so I still need a line in the code below that I use to change also `,` to a `.`

I have also attempted to use the following code:

```
cell.Value = Replace(Left(str2, 7), "-", "") & Replace(Left(str2, 7), ",", ".")
```

but I was unsuccessful.

Please see example:

```
For Each cell In Range("o2:o50000")
    Dim str2 As String
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        str2 = cell.Value
        cell.Value = Replace(Left(str2, 7), "-", "") 'Left(str2, 6)
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: `cell.Value = Replace(replace(Left(str2, 7), "-", ""),",",".")`

Comment: dont work still all , are in some values    when vba is openening the worksheet first part of the code works  cell.Value = Replace(replace(Left(str2, 7), "-", "")  second part not                                                 
319,03
387,03
307,237
345,036
351,039
319,032
309,131
309,131
309,131
318,032
309,039
310,136
3003
3002
310,032
310,037
310,032
5233
5233
302,131
302,132

Comment: Jurgen, if you are replying to someone in your comments, you need to tag them [@ScottCraner]

Comment: how to format it then when my userform is opening the worksheet @K.Dᴀᴠɪs

Comment: but can i do vba excell code do that for me when opening the worksheet

Comment: There is a `Workbook_Open()` event you can use, yes, but the macro has to be a part of that XLSM file already for it to automatically trigger. But if you put the routine in an XLAM file (Add-In) then you can make a Ribbon Button for it so then you can just open the XLSX file and then click the Ribbon button.

Comment: @JürgenLambrecht, this seems to be a separator issue. You can simply change the decimal and thousands separator from the settings. 319,00 will then be represented as 319.00.

Comment: @Arul     yes i understand it but then the other item numers like 65299 will be seperated with a point      like this 65.299     but then i can't see the item picture anymore in my userform   the items within thousands must stay like it is    i just want to replace when my userform is opening the worksheet   items like 319,018 and a few hunderd more items to 319.018  in it not manualy but a code that can be used when opening my userform                   hope that someone can help here